# Solve the surface integral for $F = (xz, x^2 y^2 z, xyz)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to calculate;

$$\int_{s}\operatorname{curl} \vec F\cdot \, d\vec A$$

where $\vec F = (xz, x^2 y^2 z, xyz)$ and when S is the open surface given by the cylinder, (with no ends) of radius a, centred on the x-axis with equation $y^2 + z^2 = a^2$
and $0 ≤ x ≤ 5$

Comment: Please format the math so we don't have to guess what you mean. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @DavidK Done, please if there is something you don't understand just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or calculate it "as is"

$$\nabla\times\vec F=(x(z-xy^2),x-yz,2xy^2z)$$

The surface is in a suitable parametrization:

$$\vec r=
\begin{cases}
 x=u\\
 y=a\cos v\\
 z=a\sin v
\end{cases}$$

$d\vec A=\vec r_v\times\vec r_u dudv=(0,-a\sin v,a\cos v)\times(1,0,0) dudv=(0,a\cos v,a\sin v)dudv$

$\nabla\times\vec F·d\vec A=(u(a\sin v-ua^2\cos^2v),u-a^2\sin v\cos v,2ua^3\cos^2v\sin v)·(0,a\cos v,a\sin v)dudv=$

$=ua\cos v+a^2\cos^2 v(2ua^2\sin^2v-a\sin v)dvdu$

$$\int_S\nabla\times\vec F·d\vec A=\int_0^5\int_0^{2\pi}(ua\cos v+a^2\cos^2 v(2ua^2\sin^2v-a\sin v))dvdu=$$

$$=\int_0^5\dfrac{\pi a^4u}{2}du=\dfrac{25a^4\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but how did you go from the penultimate line to the final line. Like that integral looks incredibly difficult. Thanks

Comment: I let wolfram did the work. It's very cumbersome, but not difficult to calculate. You have a cosine plus an almost immediate integral, with cosine squared but with $d(\cos)=\sin x$ ready to use. The third term needs some more steps, the first is transform it in sum of two even powers of cosine...

Comment: you can cancel half of it though, as cos is an odd function, and you're going over the whole period. Also this works for $cos^2(v)sin(v)$ too as you have an odd time and even i think

Comment: It's so for the first and third terms, yes. The second has both squared.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Stokes' theorem and evaluate your integral as follows:
$$\int_{S}{\vec{\mathrm{curl}}\vec{F}}\cdot\vec{n}dA=\int_{C}{\vec{F}|_{x=0}\cdot\,d\vec{r}}-\int_{C}{\vec{F}|_{x=5}\cdot\,d\vec{r}}\tag{*}$$

Parameterising the curve $C$ as 
$\vec{r}=(x,a\,\cos\theta,a\,\sin{\theta})$, where $x$ is a constant taking values $0$ and $5$, you can compute contour integrals in $(*)$ easily.

The minus sign in the second integral is due to the change of direction when integrating upper with respect to lower base contour.

Therefore:
$$\vec{F}|_{x=0}=(0,0,0)\qquad \vec{F}|_{x=5}=5(z,5y^2z,yz)$$

And your integral supposing $\vec{n}$ the uter normal vector to the cylinder
$$\int_{S}{\vec{\mathrm{curl}}\vec{F}}\,\vec{n}dA=-\int_{C}{5(z,5y^2z,yz)\cdot\,d\vec{r}}$$
Now if we integrate last contour integral over $C$ we have
$$\int_{C}{5(z,5y^2z,yz)\cdot\,d\vec{r}}=\int_{C}{5(\sin{\theta},5\cos^2{\theta}\sin{\theta},\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})\cdot\,\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}d\theta}$$
where the curve you are integrating over imposes that
$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}=a(0,-\sin{\theta},\cos{\theta})$$

Can you keep going from this?

Hope I have not committed any mistake.

Comment: the part I couldn't do was the parameterisation. That's why i need help

Comment: Are you allowed to do the parameterisation? Or you must do without it?

Comment: Yeah I can parametrise it. What I thought was that $\vec X(p,q)$ =(q, acos(p), asin(p)) where q goes from 0 to 5 and p from 0 to 2pi

Comment: $q$ is constant over your two curves, coincided with the radius of the cylinder. Anyways, I've edited my post. Hope it helps

Comment: The cylinder is of radius $a$. Not sure about the sign...